# Installing MySQL Utilities on OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-elcapitan

Wanted to use `mysqldbcopy`, which is part of MySQL Utilities. The latest release (mysql-utilities-1.5.6-osx10.9.dmg) appears to be for Mavericks, and attempting to use it results in the warning: "This package is incompatible with this version of OS X and may fail to install." Spoiler alert, it *does* fail to install.

I found [these instructions](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?144,636638,636658#msg-636658), which seem promising:

1. You need Connector/Python installed in your system. Download it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
2. Download MySQL Utilities source code by selecting "Source Code" from "Select Platform" in http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/
3. Follow the instructions of MySQL Utilities installation from source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-install-source.html

I have Python installed, but am a little unclear about step 2. The download options for source code download list only has options for Windows and a few flavors of Linux. Anybody know which one to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to install MySQL Utilities from source code.  The downloads listed for the platform "source code" were all labelled "Architecture Independent" so I figured it didn't matter which one I used.

1. You need Connector/Python installed in your system. Download it from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
2. Download MySQL Utilities source code by selecting "Source Code" from "Select Platform" in http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/utilities/

   - I downloaded the Windows distribution and unzipped it
3. From a terminal:

   - `$ cd path/to/unzipped/mysql-utilities-1.5.6`
   - `$ python ./setup.py build`
   - `$ sudo python ./setup.py install`

That all seemed to work great and `mysqldbcopy` is now available.  I forget it I had to close and reopen my terminal, but, depending on your setup, you might have to do that.

Comment: I found an Oracle forum thread on this topic. It starts back in Nov 2015, and still looks to be active. The latest message is on Nov 21 2016 by someone from Oracle, they seem to be close to having a fix for the utils. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?144,636638,652767#msg-652767